# Issue when converting microseconds to datatimeoffset c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time, datetimeoffset

I am trying to convert microseconds to DateTime. Please find the code below,

long microSecs = 1632489907280; // **Working**

long microSecs = 1650391805000000 // **Not working** -- It has nanoseconds also.

```
DateTimeOffset utc = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(microSecs).UtcDateTime;
 return utc.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
```

Anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: You're trying to convert "micro" seconds with a function named "milli" seconds. I question your definition of "working" in the first case.

Comment: `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` says it clear: MILLI seconds, not micro seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffZ
```

The format `.fff` is for milliseconds. Your example `1632489907280` is also in milliseconds, so it works fine. But the other case, instead of milliseconds is in microseconds, so the former format does not work anymore. You need 6 `f` symbols to deal with microseconds.

Comment: No. When I am converting unixtimemilliseconds level itself I got the exception.

Comment: If you want to deal with both, milliseconds and microseconds, I think you will have to change you function logic to be able to distinguish if the UNIX format you provided was in milliseconds, or in microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

### why first input is working and second input is not working?

There is no built-in method from `DateTime` class to process epoc microseconds

In your first example, `1632489907280` is within the `milliseconds` range, so `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds()` considering `1632489907280` as milliseconds not microseconds.

In your second case, `1650391805000000` is **greater than** the max range of milliseconds.

From [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=net-6.0#exceptions), `DateTime.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(milliseconds)` throws an [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-6.0) if the

> milliseconds is less than -62,135,596,800,000.
>
> -or-
>
> milliseconds is greater than **253,402,300,799,999**.

---

To fix the error, convert your microseconds to milliseconds and then pass it to `DateTime.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(milliseconds)`.

Try below code,

```
public static string ProcessEpocTime(long microSecs)
{
    //Convert microseconds to Milliseconds.
    long milliSecs = (long)microSecs / 1000; 
    DateTimeOffset utc = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(milliSecs).UtcDateTime;
    return utc.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
}
```

<sub>**Note:** This solution will work for valid microseconds value.</sub>

[Try online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aIu3Fx)